# Can one create a two-part spacing command?

Tags: spacing

I would like to create a two-part spacing command.  Specifically, I'd like two commands: `\mySpaceOne` and `\mySpaceTwo`.  If `\mySpaceOne` is followed by a `\mySpaceTwo`, then it generates a certain amount of space; otherwise, it does nothing and does not consume the next token.

Is this possible?  How would one begin to create such a command?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: This is doable, but depends on what you mean by "followed by", and what is meant by not "followed by". So, the test case should cover these cases.

Comment: Understood; thanks for the heads up.  My lack of an MWE reflected my uncertainty as to exactly what it was I wanted here.  Not knowing TeX as well as I would like, I didn't want to limit my possibilities by requesting something too specific.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mySpaceOne{\@ifnextchar\mySpaceTwo{\hspace{1em}}{}}
\makeatother
```

This will consume all space tokens, however.

Comment: I think you might consider adding `\let\mySpaceTwo\relax` to enable `\mySpaceTwo` to be standalone command doing nothing.

Comment: This is simple and works just as I asked.  At this point, though, I'm not sure why it doesn't seem to work in a command.  I created `\newcommand{\hello}{\mySpaceTwo hello \mySpaceOne}` and then tried `\hello\hello`, but there is no space between them; this is probably because the first `\mySpaceOne` sees the `\hello` coming up (since it hasn't expanded yet).  Defining `\newcommand{\hello}{\mySpaceTwo hello \expandafter\mySpaceOne}` also didn't help.  Any suggestions?

Comment: With the `\expandafter` it works and it obviously can't work with the first definition: TeX sees `\hello`, which is not `\mySpaceTwo`. You're probably not using the right approach, but it's difficult to say more without knowing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Similar answer to egreg but using the TeX primitive `\futurelet`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\myspacetwo{}
\def\myspaceone{%
 \futurelet\ifoptions
    \choosemacro
}

\def\choiceone{\rule{20pt}{20pt}}
\def\choicetwo{}
\def\choosemacro{%
 \ifx\ifoptions\myspacetwo%
     \let\choice = \choiceone 
 \else
    \let\choice = \choicetwo
 \fi
\choice
}
\myspaceone\myspacetwo 
\myspaceone
\end{document}
```

A `\futurelet` takes normally three tokens:

```
     \futurelet\tokena\tokenb\tokenc
```

TeX executes a `let\tokena=\tokenc` generating a copy of `\tokenc` stored under the name of `\tokena`.

It then removes `\tokena` from the main token list. Following TeX expands `\tokenb`.

This token is for all practical purposes a macro with the following
properties:

1. The macro will use `\tokena`, which is a copy of `\tokenc`, to find
   out what `\tokenc` is, in other words what token is to be expected
   later.
2. It then causes another macro to be expanded which will ultimately
   absorb `\tokenc`.